# Time.sleep() suspending the execution - Python

Tags: python, reddit, praw

So I'm making a Reddit Bot in Python, using the code from this [repository](https://github.com/shantnu/RedditBot/blob/master/Part2/reply_post.py).

And its working fine. But as per Reddit guidelines, I can comment only every 10 minutes. So I'm using a `for` loop here and the last part of the code is something like this:

```
i=1
for submission in subreddit.hot(limit=10):
    if not os.path.isfile("posts_replied_to.txt"):
        posts_replied_to = []

    # Or load the list of posts we have replied to
    else:
        with open("posts_replied_to.txt", "r") as f:
            posts_replied_to = f.read()
            posts_replied_to = posts_replied_to.split("\n")
            posts_replied_to = list(filter(None, posts_replied_to))
# Pull the hottest 10 entries from a subreddit of your choosing
    #print(submission.title)
    if(i%5!=0):
    # Make sure you didn't already reply to this post
        if submission.id not in posts_replied_to:

            # Not case sensitive
            if re.search("backpacking", submission.title, re.IGNORECASE):
                # Reply
                foo=['Awesome','Pretty nice eh!','Cool','Very beautiful','I would love to go there',\
                    'I also want to try it out now', 'Really cool', 'Can\'t wait to go there', 'Nice']
                random_index = randrange(len(foo))
                submission.reply(foo[random_index])

                print("Bot replying to : ", submission.title)

                # Store id in list
                posts_replied_to.append(submission.id)
    else:
        if submission.id not in posts_replied_to:

            # Not case sensitive
            if re.search("backpacking", submission.title, re.IGNORECASE):
                # Reply
                foo=['https://****.in']
                random_index = randrange(len(foo))
                submission.reply(foo[random_index])

                print("Bot replying to : ", submission.title)

                # Store id in list
                posts_replied_to.append(submission.id)    
    i+=1
    with open("posts_replied_to.txt", "w") as f: # Write updated list to file
        for post_id in posts_replied_to:
            f.write(post_id + "\n")
    time.sleep(600) #10 minutes delay
```

So for top 10 subreddits under backpacking I want to post every 10 mintues and for every 5th comment I want to post a link, that is why I'm using the `if (i%5)!=0`.

Now here you can see I have added the `time.sleep()` at the last. When I comment it out, it is executing fine and while making the 2nd comment it shows API exception error try to post after 9 minutes which is legit based on Reddit guidelines.

But when I'm using `time.sleep()` function it is not executing anymore, I have waited more than 10 minutes, around half and hour but still its not executing, I'm not able to get why!

Is there also any limitation to no. of comments per day? I haven't found any, so if anyone know please!

P.S. My main motive is to execute that posting function every 10 mintues, need not be `time.sleep()` if there is any other suitable functions. Please don't suggest cronjob.

Comment: Sorry, your question isn't clear. `time.sleep(600)` puts your program to sleep for 10 minutes. Of course it can't execute anything while it's asleep.

Comment: yes, but i have waited more than 10 minutes and still its not executing. I've updated the question

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post a [mcve] that reproduces this sleep problem, preferably something that doesn't rely on posting to reddit, so that we can test it easily. To make sure your code is not executing, put a simple print line after the `sleep` call, eg `print('Awake!')`. You could also print the time before & after the `sleep` call.

Comment: Your condition `if(i%5!=0)` will only true after **5 times awaiting time.sleep(...)** which results in **50 Minutes**. Do the opposite, `time.sleep(5 * 60)` and comment every second loop.

Comment: I suggest you use apscheduler. It is reliable and simple to schedule function calls. You can read the documentation here: https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide.html